# Remote Debug Win8 Surface App from VS2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to debug a Windows Store app from within VS2012 on a Microsoft Surface RT tablet. Both the desktop development system and the Surface tablet are on the same subnet (191.168.1.x). I've installed the Remote Debugging Tools for ARM on the tablet, and can fire up the Remote Debugging Monitor on it.

When I try to Find the tablet from within the VS2012 project's Debug property page, nothing is found (i.e., the find process can't locate the tablet). From running ipconfig on the tablet I know that its IP address is 192.168.1.140. The desktop system's IP address is 192.168.1.2.

My desktop system is part of a domain, which I know introduces complications. I've made the user accounts on the two systems identical in terms of user names and passwords (the desktop user ID is mark, in the "example.com" domain, while the tablet's user ID is "mark@example.com").

I tried configuring the remote debugger on the tablet to ignore authentication (i.e., setting it to allow any user to debug, and not enforcing security). The problem still persists.

This feels like a "port not open", or "port blocked by firewall" issue. But I can't find any documentation on what ports VS2012 needs for remote debugging.

FWIW, I did notice one thing in the midst of flailing around: pinging the tablet from the desktop, or the desktop from the tablet, fails. As does `tracert`. Yet both machines are connected to the internet through my Linux firewall/router, and the Linux system can ping both the desktop and the tablet.

Comment: This sounds more like a networking problem than specific to VS2012 or the remote debugger? Do other protocols like SMB folder sharing work?

Comment: Extraneous comments that make the question less useful to others attempting to solve a similar problem are discouraged.  This has nothing to do with Microsoft or any other non-SO entity.

Comment: Hello! If you would like to have your question deleted, please **flag for moderator attention** as opposed to changing your question body. With respect to your edit's content: [Stack Overflow is a community-edited and maintained site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing). Humor is fine, but your *placement* of it makes it look more like a rant than a funny bit of chatter. Remember: on the internet, no one can hear your tone.

Comment: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/10/26/remote-debugging-windows-store-apps-on-surface-arm-devices.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+timheuer+%28Method+~+of+~+failed+by+Tim+Heuer%29