# HTML Remote debugging for Microsoft Surface RT

Tags: html, remote-debugging, developer-tools, windows-rt

Hi I am developing a web app (HTML, Js, CSS) that has to be available also on touch devices, including IE 10/11 on Microsoft Surface RT Tablets.

The point is I would like to attach my PC’s Explorer’s developers Tools to the device to be able to inspect HTML/CSS and debug JS like I do with Firebug or any browser dev tools, (as I have already done with Firefox for Nexus Google and Safari – with a MAC – for iPad) but I cannot make it or find resources about it.

I have only found so far [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339222/remote-debug-win8-surface-app-from-vs2012) and [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40781), which is probably for Store Apps (I have not yet installed it) and I was wondering if there was something simpler than installing an extension to Visual Studio, even though I have Windows 8.1 and VS2013. If possible I would rather use just Explorer and the developer tools for ‘simple’ HTML-JS-CSS debugging. Thank you.

Comment: Have you successfully tried using Visual Studio to remote debug IE in Surface mode?

Comment: I have not yet tried, also because I for the moment solved that debugging problem I had. But in the future I will probably try this solution since it seems there is no alternative, which is a bit of a pity because other browsers do support remote debugging